# Excel Vb to Send email to multiple recipients

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code which sends emails to one recipient. I have a sheet with three recipients.

I have tried changing the code to `XLUp.value` `XLDown.value` and changed the range and tried range names. None of these worked.

This part of the code does not seem to work

```
Dim SendTo As String
Dim BuildAddy As Integer
' Sheets("Emails").Select

'For BuildAddy = 1 To Range("A1048000").End(xlUp).Row ' ie the last value in the column

For BuildAddy = 1 To Range("A1:A").End(xlUp).Row   ' ie the last value in the column
    SendTo = SendTo & Range("A1:A" & BuildAddy).Value & ";" ' at least I think it's a ;.  It might be a ,
Next BuildAddy

.To = SendTo
.To = Sheets("Emails").Range("A1:A").Value ' <-- Put email of the recipient here
```

Comment: `Range("A1:A")` is no valid syntax!

Answer (score 0):

`Range("A1:A")` is no valid address because the row number in the end is missing.

It should be something like …

```
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

accordingly it should be

```
SendTo = SendTo & Range("A" & BuildAddy).Value & ";"
```

Also you should specify for all `Range(…)` in which worksheet the range is. Like `Worksheets("Emails").Range(…)` otherwise Excel cannot know that.

Comment: Which part of the code i need to edit to add working solution

Comment: **Every** part that includes the wrong syntax I explained needs to be fixed. See my edit.